# Can I split an ObjectOutputStream into several files

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I want to write data from my game into a file, so I can recreate the state after restarting my program.
Currently I am using javas default (de-)serialialization, as it takes care of circular references and duplicate objects all by itself and therefore is very easy to use. Now when serializing, all the data is written into one single file, what seems to be pretty unpractical, if the file gets corrupted. That would effectively mean all data is lost. I'd rather have the data written into several smaller, topic-related files, such as player data, world data, enemy data, etc... . Can this be accomplished, **without** having to create new ObjectOutputStreams over and over again, because I want to use the internal duplicate object detection?
Before switching to Java default serialization, I used fasterxml and the json format, which sadly did not provide as comfortable handling of duplicates and circular references, as Java does. On the other hand storing the data into several smaller files was no problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't the probability of corruption not increase proportionally to the number of files involved? 
Corruption would be easier to fix, btw, with the human-readable `XMLSerializer`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> as it takes care of circular references and duplicate objects all by itself and therefore is very easy to use.

You said it.

You have two options:

[1] You take java's default serialization mechanism, which is 'easy to use' but it is what it is. You can't modify how it works, you don't get files that you can read with anything except java's serialization mechanism, and it's pretty tricky to update your game and still be able to read older save files (you *can*, but do that for a few versions and the total amount of code in your codebase dedicated to reading save files will be longer and considerably more complicated than if you had just saved using e.g. jackson to XML or json or even protobuf and rolled your own code in the first place).

[2] You write your own system.

You can't have your cake and eat it too, which is what you're asking for.

Note that trying to protect against disk corruption is a fine enough goal, but 'save into smaller files' is like adding a third lock to the door whilst the windows are wide open. Theoretically it helps, but you're focussing on entirely the wrong thing.

For example, if one file is corrupted, the rest are fine - so what? You still can't load the game. If your intent is: Ah, but now I can go in and fix this one file - great. The problem isn't "multiple files", the problem is that you want a save file format you can reasonably edit. java's built-in serialization mechanism utterly fails this requirement and can't be fixed in that regard.

Good ideas:

- Add checksums.
- Write a save file format that is disconnected from your in memory representations. You said it yourself: There are circular refs and duplicate objects all over the place in your memory representation. Those are probably all good ideas when running the game, but in save games, that is *really bad* if you want your save files to stand a snowball's chance of surviving some corruption.
- Make multiple saves.
- Most of all: Ensure that save game file is as small as it can reasonably be: Smaller files write faster (meaning you can make more of them).
- Make sure they back up easy. You **do not want** multiple files, in fact. Zip em up if you have to. Single small files are the best way: You can autosave at the drop of a hat (smaller files also write faster!) and even save them to the cloud or backup disks or whatnot. If it's a few kb and the user has a dropbox, gdrive, onedrive etc folder, you can just spam savegames in there. That's not so reasonable if a savegame is 50MB. You should zip that file even if it's just the one file (you can use `GZipOutputStream` and co for this). Note that if you use string keys (JSON or XML), zipping will save you a ton of space. If you're using a binary format (e.g. protobuf), it'll make less of a difference.. but I'd still zip it up.
- Write a tool that goes through a save game and at least attempts to correct any errors. Java's serialization mechanism is an opaque binary format, meaning it fails the task for this one: You can't read that and fix problems.

Comment: Thats a very comprehensive answer. I'll probably try to write my own system, using fasterxml again and storing objects in a hashmap to prevent duplicate objects when loading. Thats going to take some time and effort, but I really want to handle this the right way. Zipping up files is something so simple, yet so effective but I did not even think about it. Thanks a lot